# rtrim php equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, character-trimming

I would like to know how to accomplish the
PHP

```
query = rtrim($query, '& ');
```

in C# ASP .NET MVC

I have tried `Strings.RTrim("string")` but it does not work.

Have also tried `query = query.Trim(query, "&");` but it gives me error.

Also msdn provides code for rtrim in visual basic, which does not help.

From looking at the code it seems like its' trimming the whitespace if found after & character.

Anyone know how to replicate the php command?
Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.Trim()` method removes whitespaces from both the start and end of the string, so

```
"   Hello World   ".Trim() -> "Hello World"
```

For performing the RTrim() you can use the `TrimEnd()` method with the String.

```
"   Hello World   ".TrimEnd() -> "   Hello World"
```

Comment: Ahh ofcourse it's only applying to the end of the string. makes sense now. TrimEnd() is the go :) Thanks @Sudheesh Singanamalla

Comment: You're welcome @WebDevGuy , You can accept this as an answer if it worked for you. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

C# Has pretty neat **String** trimming methods.

I'm listing different options below. Although, the one you are looking for is

```
StringVariable.TrimEnd();
"This string ends here.  ".TrimEnd();   //This also works.
```

## String-trimming methods

```
string message = "    Hello!   ";
message.TrimEnd();    // Trims from the right side.
message.TrimStart();  // Trims from the left side.
message.Trim();       // Trims on both sides
```

## Summary

`message.TrimEnd()` will trim from the right side of the string variable.

`message.TrimStart()` will trim from the left side of the string variable.

`message.Trim()` will trim from both sides of the string variable.

> Also msdn provides code for rtrim in visual basic, which does not help.

I found a few that might help you, and they have them in multiple .NET languages, including C#.

[Microsoft - String.Trim Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Microsoft - String.TrimEnd Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Microsoft - String.TrimStart Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this ==>

```
string.Remove(string.LastIndexOf("&"));
```

> With the help of remove last index you can remove the last element